# What exactly do I need alter to get the desired result in tracert?

Tags: batch-file, traceroute

Looking for some batch file code which uses `tracert`, I found this:

[Process "Tracert" output for IP addresses (Batch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905525/process-tracert-output-for-ip-addresses-batch)

I'm not an expert in batch files, and I tried to alter the domain to a specific one, but I'm getting this error:

[image: Error image]

What exactly should I alter to get a result file like this, but using the domain that I want:

```
Hop: 1  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 0ms    IP: 192.168.1.1  
Hop: 2  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 0ms    IP: 10.59.17.1  
Hop: 3  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 2ms    IP: 172.17.2.137  
Hop: 4  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 6ms    IP: 172.17.4.36  
Hop: 5  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 4ms    IP: 172.17.4.10  
Hop: 6  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 2ms    IP: 172.17.4.3  
Hop: 7  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 3ms    IP: 80.72.159.241       Host: lt-0-0-0.mx-1a.ip.cirque.dk
Hop: 8  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 2ms    IP: 194.255.185.193     Host: 0xc2ffb9c1.linknet.dk.telia.net
Hop: 9  Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 2ms    IP: 194.255.133.97      Host: 0xc2ff8561.linknet.dk.telia.net
Hop: 10 Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 5ms    IP: 194.255.133.98      Host: 0xc2ff8562.linknet.dk.telia.net 
Hop: 11 Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 3ms    IP: 87.72.143.234  
Hop: 12 Packetloss: ---             Average: ---    IP: Timeout
Hop: 13 Packetloss: ---             Average: ---    IP: Timeout
Hop: 14 Packetloss: 0 (0% loss)     Average: 3ms    IP: 62.61.131.22        Host: speedtest01-hor.aplus.dk
```

Comment: `tracert`, doesn't provide a packet loss column, it provides three columns, each which can be added together and, I suppose divided by three, _(with rounding)_, to achieve an average. So essentially you appear to be asking somebody to write some code which modifies the output of a specifc utility, and adds new functionality to it. Regardless of your level of experience, the question is both unreasonable and off topic.

Comment: Oh, i see, thanks  :3